# If I've set up a Financial Type of In-Kind Donation, how should I properly set up the required Payment Instrument?

Tags: civicontribute

I've looked at other questions and answers similar to this, but I am still unsure of the best way to proceed. I am aware that I can add a payment instrument and call it whatever I want (e.g. In-Kind Material Donation or In-Kind Volunteer Time), but I would also have to assign it a Financial Account. We have many Financial Accounts set up for managing different types of transactions, but the four that show up in the New Payment Instruments Option window are Accounts Receivable, Deposit Bank Account, Payment Processor Account, and Premiums Inventory. So my questions are: When I set up a new Payment Instrument for In-Kind Donations, which Financial Account should I link it to? Should I choose one of those 4, or should I choose the In-Kind Donation financial account that I created? If I should choose the In-Kind Donation financial account, how do I get it to show up as one of my choices on the New Payment Instruments Option Financial Account drop-down box?

[image: Payment Details section of Record Contribution window]
[image: Financial Type drop-down box in Record Contribution window]
[image: Payment Instruments Options window]
[image: New Payment Instruments Option window]

Answer (score 1):

In order for the 'In-Kind' financial account to show as an option when you setup a new payment instrument it needs to be setup as an Asset account.

You should review the account relationships (under Financial Types) to make sure they meet your needs.

Depending on your accounting setup and reporting requirements I recommend looking closely at this setup to assure you get the results you require.

Hope this Helps!